# Treating a pre-defined function as a variable for differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I just started using Mathematica for my thesis, so I'm still a bit clueless about what's going on.

I have an expression for the Hamiltonian of a system wrt 4 dynamic variables (r, u, v and lambda) and its canonical momenta (pr, pu, pv). I've defined all variables initially.

**How do I get Mathematica to differentiate wrt the specific variable that I want instead of its expansion**? For example, if I want to differentiate wrt 'pr', I want Mathematica to treat 'pr' as a variable, instead of its expression that was defined earlier.

My code is attached:

```
OverDot[u[t_]] := D[u, t]
OverDot[v[t_]] := D[v, t]
OverDot[r[t_]] := D[r, t]
OverDot[\[Lambda][t_]] := D[\[Lambda], t]
Subscript[p, r] := m*v*(r*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(.\)]\) + v*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(r\), \(.\)]\))
Subscript[p, u] := m*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(.\)]\)
Subscript[p, v] := m*(r^2*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(.\)]\) + r*v*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(r\), \(.\)]\) + u^2*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(v\), \(.\)]\))

Subscript[H, p] = ((r^2 + u^2)*Subscript[p, r]^2 - 
   2*r*v*Subscript[p, r]*Subscript[p, v] + 
   v^2*(u^2 Subscript[p, u]^2 + Subscript[p, v]^2))/(
  2*m*u^2*v^2) + \[Lambda]*(r - a) + Subscript[np, \[Lambda]]

D[%, Subscript[p, r]]
```

If I evaluate the final line, it would say "General::ivar: m v (v Overscript[r, .]+r Overscript[v, .]) is not a valid variable."

Comment: I recommend that you do not use `OverDot`, `SubScript`, etc.  They may look nice but often cause problems in symbolic computations.  I suspect that your code has other problems as well, but clean this up first.

Comment: The specific error message occurs, because you cannot differentiate with respect to  `Subscript[p, r]`.